# Predictive model giving only one class on holdout set keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Currently, using a CNN to predict a model for some black and white images.  The model is working well for what I want it to do. This is the model:

```
lr = 0.2
Adam(lr=lr, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.001)
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
dropout = 0.3
# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Dropout(rate=dropout))
# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Dropout(rate=dropout))
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
epoch_number = 40
epochs = 25
steps_validation = 100
history = classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = epoch_number,
                         epochs = epochs,
                         validation_data = test_set,
validation_steps = steps_validation)  
classifier.save('epoch40epochs25softmax.h5')
```

Now, after I train this model I want to use it in the 'real world' so I have a holdout set that I use it on. The problem is it only predicts class 1 when I do a `classifier.predict_classes(test_image)` I figured I was doing something wrong so I tried doing a `classifier.predict_classes(test_image)` for all the elements in the testing set since I knew I was getting 75% accuracy on that set and still upon doing a:

```
for test_image in test_set_dir:
    classifier.predict_classes(test_image)
```

I am still only getting numbers very close to `[[1]]`. My question is am I using keras correctly, or if not, what is going on?  I should get some `[[0]]` classifications.

I am absolutely sure that the model is not predicting just class 1 since I have a 50% - 50% split on the two classes and I am getting 75% accuracy.

Edit:
I am normalizing the images thusly

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0,  
                                   zoom_range = 0,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('datasetI/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('datasetI/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')
```

If I want to get the class prediction on the test_set what should I do to get it?

Comment: You are most likely not normalizing the images the same way the training set was normalized. Add more information (like the definition of the generator) to get a more detailed answer.

Comment: Hey i can't see the "classifier.compile(...)" step in your code, did you compile it? where?

Comment: @mctrjalloh yea I somehow missed that line of code it's in now.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro added it

Comment: Do you see the rescale parameter in both of your generators? You have to apply it to any image that you load, which is the missing normalization.

Comment: How do I do this @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: Currently I am doing     `test_image = image.load_img('./datasetI/test_set/queen11/'+filename, target_size = (64,64))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)`

Comment: then a `classifier.predict(test_image)`

Comment: divide test_image by 255 before giving it to predict

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro that works thanks I thought you might have to use some fancy rescaled function.